# MySQL query function that keeps previous records in mind

Tags: mysql, database, function

first off, I couldn't come up with a proper title, suggestions are welcome.

I have a database which stores users and groups. users can be part of multiple groups, and groups have a certain "authorityLevel". Authoritylevel is an integer of which the binary form represents the authorities (5 is 101, so you have authority for the first, and third option, and none for the second).

The query I made that looks for your authority level, checks through all the groups and selects the highest authority level.
but this of course doesn't work, (if you have authority level 3 (110) from one group, and authority level 5 (101) from another group, then you should have authority level 7 (111), but it will select the max, which is 5).
is there a way I can make a function that I can put in the query, which looks at the binary representation for each time it finds a value, and then returns the proper authority level?
(the MAX function for example, looks at all found values, and compares them)

current Query "SELECT MAX(managementAuthorityLevel) AS lvl FROM user u INNER JOIN CTgroupUser gu on u.ID = gu.user INNER JOIN `group` g ON gu.group = g.name WHERE u.ID = :ID;"
with :ID being PHP PDO statement parameter
[logical model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u660e.png)

because this is not the only place I would need it, I would like to do it without using a procedure.

thanks for reading

Comment: Please add some data and your current query to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, then you need a bitwise maximum as opposed to the maximum of the entire number. This means that if a bit is set to 1 for any of the groups, then the result should be 1. This corresponds to the bitwise `or` operation.

MySQL has bitwise aggregate functions, which includes [bit_or()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or):

> Returns the bitwise OR of all bits in expr. The calculation is
>   performed with 64-bit (BIGINT) precision.
>
> If there are no matching rows, BIT_OR() returns a neutral value (all
>   bits set to 0).

So you can simply use `bit_or()` on the field that contains the access rights grouped by on the user id.